# Does Azure allow hosting of n-tier applications?

Tags: azure

In Visual Studio 2013, I have a solution that holds several projects, including multiple class libraries, as well as an MVC5 project to serve HTML pages to clients.If I get the free tier, can I host my entire solution, including all the projects that it holds? Microsoft's own documentation on this matter is not clear, and I was hoping someone here has already used the Azure platform for hosting their website.

**Does Microsoft's Azure Hosting allow the hosting of n-tier applications?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not? You can host every tier of your application separatly in Azure (DBs, web sites, services, background jobs, etc.) in different services provided by Azure. In the free tier you have the limitation of sites you can create for free (Azure Web Sites), limitation of cores (don't know the exact limit) and the costs you produce. If your costs exceeds the limit all of your resources will be shut down.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question wrong. Can every tier of my solution be hosted under 1 free tier hosting plan, or will I have to get a free tier hosting plan for every project in my solution? My solution has 6 projects inside it. I'm only using it for testing small projects, as soon as I want to go big with one of them I plan to upgrade my free tier plan.

Comment: Are you talking about Azure Web Sites or the Azure trial?

Comment: I'm talking about the free tier detailed on this page: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/ . It says "10 unique websites/apps", but I'm not sure whether that means you can host 10 solutions with 1 project in them each, or if it means the total amount of projects inside all your solutions can't be higher than 10.

Comment: You can host up to ten websites (such as MVC projects), but the rest depends on the structure of your project/application. If you consume your class libraries from your website they count as one resource (because they are deployed as a single unit). If they are separate services you need to create one per service (where every service/website is a single unit). I think you mixed up tiers with layers. You can host a layered application in one website, but a tiered application needs one deployment per tier (so you can use up to ten tiers maximum).